# Angular $digest cycle refreshes the entire view instead of a portion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am facing a strange issue in Angular 1 which is causing the script to go into **infinite loop** and eventually the browser hangs.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
<script>
    $scope.A = true;
    $scope.B = [{blah},{blah}];
    $scope.updateB = function(){
        $scope.B.push({blah});
    }
    $scope.D = function(key){
        $scope.A = false;
        return key.name;
    }
</script>

    <div ng-if="A">
        <button ng-click="updateB()"></button>
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="key in B">
      {{D(key)}}
    </div>
```

**So basically I want to hide first div after the button is pressed. I know I can do it in "updateB" function. But no, I want to do that in "D", after the expression is evaluated. It goes into an infinite loop.**

Can anybody suggest me what is going wrong here ?

Comment: @estus If I update B, the expression will be evaluated and D() will be invoked again and ultimately $scope.A = false. What is the issue in this flow ?

Comment: I think this is the right behavior. D() will be invoked on every angular cycle. If you have one or more elements in B, your function D() will be called.

Comment: Yeah I understand, D will be invoked multiple times (up to length of B), but not in infinite loop. That said, even if there is only one element in B, D is invoked repeatedly.

Comment: D() won't be invoked up to length of B. It will be invoked multiple times, on every angular digest cycle. This because you have an angular expression {{D(key)}}. Angular will evaluate this expression on every cycle.

Comment: @L.Figueredo Will it evaluate the expression "{{D(key)}}" on every digest cycle even if B is not updated ? (B is iterated in the ng-repeat)

Comment: if you don't have any element in B, your function won't be executed. But even if you have only one element, the function D() will be executed on every digest cycle. This may help you to understand how the digest cycle works: 
https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/ and 
https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/

Comment: Thanks @L.Figueredo. Understood.

Comment: No problems, I'm posting an answer because this can help another person too. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your function D() will be executed on every angular digest cycle. Even if you have only one element in B.
If you have no elements on B, your function won't be executed.

This may help you to understand how digest cycle works:
[The Digest Loop and $apply](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) and [Understanding the Digest Cycle](https://www.thinkful.com/projects/understanding-the-digest-cycle-528/)